# How to add a new column with multiple string contain conditions in python pandas other than using np.where?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, dataframe

I was trying to add a new column by giving multiple strings contain conditions using `str.contains()` and `np.where()` function. By this way, I can have the final result I want.

But, the code is very lengthy. Are there any good ways to reimplement this using pandas function?

```
df5['new_column'] = np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('gross to net', case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('gross up', case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('net to gross',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('gross-to-net',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('gross-up',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('net-to-gross',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('gross 2 net',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('net 2 gross',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('gross net',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('net gross',case=False).fillna(False),1,
    np.where(df5['sr_description'].str.contains('memo code',case=False).fillna(False),1,0)))))))))))
```

This output will be,

if those strings contain in 'sr_description' then give a `1`, else `0` to `new_column`

Maybe store the multiple string conditions in a list then read and apply them to a function.

Edit:

Sample Data:

```
sr_description                  new_column
something with gross up.           1
without those words.               0
or with Net to gross               1
if not then we give a '0'          0
```

Comment: you can use a regex that match all your cases with 'or' operator

Comment: Also you can see `numpy.select`

Comment: Whenever there is 'gross' is 1?

Comment: It’s probably better to use booleans than “0” and “1”. I think I know how to solve this, I will try to post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Could you explain what the code is meant to do?

Comment: Also, can you share some test data + more of the code?

Comment: Hi@AlexanderCécile. So sorry for the late reply. I have updated the sample data. It basically assigns values in a new column with multiple string conditions. I hope you can help me find another solution to make my code simpler.

Comment: @JiayuZhang did my answer work? I can’t remember if I changed it after your most recent update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.

**Code:**

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# list of the strings we want to check for
check_strs = ['gross to net', 'gross up', 'net to gross', 'gross-to-net', 'gross-up', 'net-to-gross', 'gross 2 net',
             'net 2 gross', 'gross net', 'net gross', 'memo code']

# From the re.escape() docs: Escape special characters in pattern. 
# This is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.
check_strs_esc = [re.escape(curr_val) for curr_val in check_strs]

# join all the escaped strings as a single regex
check_strs_re = '|'.join(check_strs_esc)

test_col_1 = ['something with gross up.', 'without those words.', np.NaN, 'or with Net to gross', 'if not then we give a "0"']
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=test_col_1, columns=['sr_description'])

df_1['contains_str'] = df_1['sr_description'].str.contains(check_strs_re, case=False, na=False)

print(df_1)
```

**Result:**

```
              sr_description  contains_str
0   something with gross up.          True
1       without those words.         False
2                        NaN         False
3       or with Net to gross          True
4  if not then we give a "0"         False
```

Note that `numpy` isn't required for the solution to function, I'm just using it to test a `NaN` value.

Let me know if anything is unclear or your have any questions! :)