# How to extract part of a string in pandas dataframe cell and create a new column with that string inside it

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns contains a lengthy string which contains a lot of information which I need to break up into separate columns and add these to the dataframe. Its similar to this [How to add a new column with multiple string contain conditions in python pandas other than using np.where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700943/how-to-add-a-new-column-with-multiple-string-contain-conditions-in-python-pandas) but I can't see how to adapt that.

I can create the empty columns but I don't know if the string can have elements extracted or if it can be separated into columns.

***e.g. Line of data***

```
0    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs
```

***Desired output***

RowNumber,     Volts, Wfm,  Sclk, Image,  Segment

1 ,               17 ,   BF27,  100 ,  1in24,   24

***Data***

```
                                              Comments  Image
0    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
1    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
2    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
3    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
4    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
..                                                 ...    ...
706  Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.5V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
707  Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.5V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
708  Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.5V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
709  Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.5V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
710  Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.5V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs      0
```

***Code***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "/Users/.../Desktop/tk_gui_grid/"
file = "orig_data.txt"
filepath = path+file

df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')

com = df.loc[:,['Comments']]
dfLen = len(com)

image = [0]*dfLen
com['Image'] = image

print(com)
```

Comment: [Here are the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) regarding regex extraction.  See if this helps.  Using the `expand` parameter will extract named groups into columns by that name.

Comment: I got this to work df['Image']=df['Comments'].str.extract(r'(1in24)')

Comment: It looks like I need multiple regex combined, I have only just looked at some of the similar questions to that and it looks like gobbledygook - it may take the weekend to get my head around.

Comment: No worries.  I'll pull something together for you now.

Comment: I don't think you need regex at all. split the string on spaces with `expand=True` and process the columns you want to keep, deleting the unwanted columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick solution using regex with named capture groups.

#### Benefit of regex over `split`:

Some have commented that regex is not required, and this is a true statement. However, from the standpoint of data validation, using regex helps to prevent 'stray' data from creeping in. Using a 'blind' `split()` function splits the data on (a character); but **what if the source data has changed?** The `split` function is blind to this. Whereas, using regex will help to highlight an issue as the pattern simply won't match. Yes, you may get an error message - but this is a good thing as you'll be alerted to a data format change, providing the opportunity to address the issue, or update the regex pattern.

#### Source data:

Additional rows simulated for demonstration.

```
0    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in24 24segs
1    Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.1V BF27 Sclk 101ns 1in24 25segs
2    Row 3 Ch475 Vi 17.2V BF27 Sclk 102ns 1in24 26segs
3    Row 4 Ch475 Vi 17.3V BF27 Sclk 103ns 1in24 27segs
4    Row 5 Ch475 Vi 17.4V BF27 Sclk 104ns 1in24 28segs
```

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

path = './orig_data.txt'
cols = ['rownumber', 'volts', 'wfm', 'sclk', 'image', 'segment']
exp = re.compile(r'^\d+\s+Row\s'
                 r'(?P<rownumber>\d+).*\s'
                 r'(?P<volts>\d+\.\d+)V\s'
                 r'(?P<wfm>\w+)\sSclk\s'
                 r'(?P<sclk>\d+)ns\s'
                 r'(?P<image>\w+)\s'
                 r'(?P<segment>\d+)segs.*$')

df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='|', header=None, names=['comment'])
df[cols] = df['comment'].str.extract(exp, expand=True)
```

#### Output:

```
                                             comment rownumber volts   wfm  \
0  0    Row 1 Ch475 Vi 17.0V BF27 Sclk 100ns 1in2...         1  17.0  BF27   
1  1    Row 2 Ch475 Vi 17.1V BF27 Sclk 101ns 1in2...         2  17.1  BF27   
2  2    Row 3 Ch475 Vi 17.2V BF27 Sclk 102ns 1in2...         3  17.2  BF27   
3  3    Row 4 Ch475 Vi 17.3V BF27 Sclk 103ns 1in2...         4  17.3  BF27   
4  4    Row 5 Ch475 Vi 17.4V BF27 Sclk 104ns 1in2...         5  17.4  BF27   

  sclk  image segment  
0  100  1in24      24  
1  101  1in24      25  
2  102  1in24      26  
3  103  1in24      27  
4  104  1in24      28
```

Comment: I have bought a book from Packt on mastering python regular expressions as I had never seen code like what you have in the exp block, I think learning regex is going to be hard but worth it, thank you S3DEV

Comment: I found what I needed to change, my data in the textfile did not have any car preceding the 'Row' cars in the Comments field, once I took that out of the first line of your exp block it all works perfectly. Reading the first chapter has paid off, thank you S3DEV

Comment: Excellent, really glad to hear it's working for you, and even happier to hear that you were able to debug the expression to remove the leading space. Good work! If you handle text regularly, you'll certainly thank yourself for getting a good hold on regex. [Here is a site](https://regexr.com/) I use regularly to debug expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trasform the Series obj into string and then you split it. After that you can access each element through its index

```
df['Comments'].str.split(' ')

0    [Row, 1, Ch475, Vi, 17.0V, BF27, Sclk, 100ns, ...

df['Comments'].str.split(' ').str[0]

Out[7]: 
0    Row

df['Comments'].str.split(' ').str[4]

Out[8]: 
0    17.0V
```

If you understood how to access each single column from the split you can assign it to a new row in your dataframe, for ex:

```
df['RowNumber'] = df['Comments'].str.split(' ').str[1]
df['Volts'] = df['Comments'].str.split(' ').str[4]
```